# How should I store the data of the liked pages by a user into Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I have used the Facebook PHP SDK to fetch the pages user likes.

```
$liked = $facebook->api('/me/likes');
```

After decoding the JSON I get the output array something like this:

```
Array ( 
[data] => Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [category] => Book [name] => Steve Jobs by Walter Isaacson [id] => 152707268157952 [created_time] => 2012-12-05T15:10:14+0000 ) 
[1] => Array ( [category] => Internet/software [name] => Evernote [id] => 30670583128 [created_time] => 2012-11-24T04:39:25+0000 ) 
[2] => Array ( [category] => Product/service [name] => HTC [id] => 112176482203770 [created_time] => 2012-11-15T06:36:59+0000 )
....
....
....
)
```

I want to store the category and name of every page the user has liked into the database table. I want to store it in such a way that I can efficiently compare two users, and get mutually liked pages. For example: When a user wants to compare the books in common with another user, the user can get the mutually liked books.

How should I store the data from the array into the table in such a way that I can use it later for comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a table (`liked_pages`) with columns for all the data you wish to store:

- user_id
- category
- name
- id
- created_time

Store the data from your array in this table.

Then given two user_ids (for this example, let's say `1` and `2`), to find mutually liked pages you could do the following:

```
SELECT id FROM liked_pages
WHERE user_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(id) = 2
```

If you wanted to extend this to only find mutually liked pages in a certain category (let's say 'books'), you would add an additional where clause `category = 'books'`.

**Edit:**

To expand on the questions you are asking in the comments, it is best practise to store only one record per row in a database table as this allows you to search and sort for relevant records when retrieving data, something which database engines are optimised for.

The alternative to this would be to [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the array and store only one entry per 
user and then retrieve the array from the database, [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it and then do all of the searching/sorting in PHP but this would be less efficient.

Comment: i could not understand the structure of the table. I will have so many categories and so many pages. Every user will have pages liked in different categories. How would I store them? Thanks :)

Comment: That is not a problem, that is why you would store the category and then you can retrieve rows for a specific category or categories.

Comment: Lets say I create a table liked_pages with the columns you mentioned. Now the user has 50 pages with 50 different categories. How would I save it in a single row? any examples?

Comment: You wouldn't - you would store 50 rows and then only retrieve the ones you are interested in when querying the database.

Comment: okay, thanks. But, would that be a good practice if the users increase say, 100,000?